# Efficiently populating rows given possible values for each variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 42 variables, each of which have different possible values.  I am aiming to create a much larger dataframe which contains a row for each possible combination of values for each of the variables.

This will be millions of rows long and too large to hold in RAM.  I have therefore been trying to make a script which appends each possible value to an existing file.  The following code works but does so too slowly to be practical (also includes only 5 variables), taking just under 5 minutes to run on my machine.

```
V1 <- c(seq(0, 30, 1), NA)
V2 <- c(seq(20, 55, 1), NA)
V3 <- c(0, 1, NA)
V4 <- c(seq(1, 16, 1), NA)
V5 <- c(seq(15, 170, 1), NA)


df_empty <- data.frame(V1 = NA, V2 = NA, V3 = NA, V4 = NA)
write.csv(df_empty, "table_out.csv", row.names = FALSE)

start <- Sys.time()
for(v1 in 1:length(V1)){
  V1_val <- V1[v1]

  for(v2 in 1:length(V2)){
    V2_val <- V2[v2]

    for(v3 in 1:length(V3)){
      V3_val <- V3[v3]

      for(v4 in 1:length(V4)){
        V4_val <- V4[v4]

        row <- cbind(V1_val, V2_val, V3_val, V4_val)
        write.table(as.matrix(row), file = "table_out.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE,col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)        
      }
    }
  }
}

print(abs(Sys.time() - start)) # 4.8 minutes
print(paste(nrow(read.csv("table_out.csv")), "rows in file"))
```

I have tested using `data.table::fwrite()` but this failed to be any faster than `write.table(as.matrix(x))`
I'm sure the issue I have is with using so many for loops but am unsure how to translate this into a more efficient approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try the following code to generate all combinations

```
M <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid,mget(x = ls(pattern = "^V\\d+"))))
```

and then you are able to save `res` to you designated file, e.g.,

```
write.table(M, file = "table_out.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE,col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: @RexParsons does is work as you expected? If think this answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thanks